# jQuery understading how to use context in functions

Tags: jquery

I need some help to understand how to implement functions that can be used in a more flexible way.
Say I have this html:

```
<h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

-- and this script:

```
$('.heading').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

It works as intended, but I would like to make the function more general, so it can be used in other contexts - something like this:

```
$('.heading').click(function() {
  collapse();
});
var collapse = function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
}
```

This obviously doesn't work as `$(this)` is not defined. But how can I achieve something similar?
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meek/01ms5fnh/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the object of element as well:

```
$('.heading').click(function() {
   collapse(this);
});
var collapse = function(_obj) {
 $(_obj).next().slideToggle();
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/db8pnwhp/)**

Comment: Ah, that simple? Thanks a lot. :-)